# if statement not working properly with variables from another method

Tags: java

I'm totally new to Java (4 days old), and I'm trying to create my first program after watching a few YouTube videos.

Basically I'm trying to make a (guess my number game).  I've created a function/method to get a random number and another function/method to get a user inputted number (both from another class called random)

I've then called these 2 values in my main method/function to be compared in a (if) statement  but every time I run the program I get the same output.

Output:

```
Welcome to The Guessing Game
*******Version 1.1**********
Enter your name please :
john
Nice to meet you john
Ok then....let's go over the rules
I'm gonna pick a number between 1 and 10
You have 4 atempts to guess otherwise i win
Good luck!!!! 
Ok i've chosen the number between 1 and 10
take a guess :
2
You are correct!!!!
```

I seem to get the same output every time ;-(

Sorry in advance for asking a maybe straight forward question.

(Do remember I'm a newbie and many thanks for your help.)

shaz

### Below is a copy of my code:

```
public class GuessMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        introduction intro = new introduction();
        intro.welcome();

        introduction enterName = new introduction();
        enterName.userName();

        introduction rules = new introduction();
        rules.explainRules();

        // introduction getN = introduction();
        // getN.getName();

        introduction glMessage = new introduction();
        glMessage.goodluckMessage();

        random pickRandNumber = new random();
        pickRandNumber.pickRandom();

        random readyMessage = new random();
        readyMessage.readysteadyGo();



        random guessNumobj = new random();
        guessNumobj.getGuessnum();

        random getNumobj = new random();
        getNumobj.getNumber();


    }




        if (guessNumobj.getGuessnum() == getNumobj.getNumber()){

            System.out.println("You are correct!!!!");

                }else if (guessNumobj.getGuessnum() > getNumobj.getNumber()){

                    System.out.println("Too high!!!!");

                        }else if (guessNumobj.getGuessnum() < getNumobj.getNumber()){

                            System.out.println("Too low!!!!");
        }

    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class introduction {

    private String name;

    public void welcome() {

        System.out.println("Welcome to The Guessing Game");
        System.out.println("*******Version 1.1**********");
    }

    public void userName() {

        System.out.println("Enter your name please :");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + name);
    }

    public void explainRules() {

        System.out.println("Ok then....let's go over the rules");
        System.out.println("I'm gonna pick a number between 1 and 10");
        System.out.println("You have 4 atempts to guess otherwise i win");

    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void goodluckMessage() {

        System.out.println("Good luck!!!! ");
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class random {

     private int number;
     private int guessNum;

    public void pickRandom () {

        Random getRandom = new Random();


        for (int counter = 1; counter <= 1; counter++) {
            number =  getRandom.nextInt(10); //this stores the random number[(10){1 to 10}] in (number;) vairiable



        }

    }

    public void readysteadyGo(){


        System.out.println("Ok i've chosen the number between 1 and 10");
        System.out.println("take a guess :");

        Scanner scanOb = new Scanner(System.in);
        guessNum = scanOb.nextInt();
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return this.number;
    }

    public int getGuessnum(){
        return this.guessNum;
    }


}
```

Comment: whats the deal with the guess check being outside of your main function?

Comment: Side note: `for (int counter = 1; counter <= 1; counter++)` can be completely removed. No need to loop if you are only doing something once. Also, you don't have to create a new object of your class every time you want to call a method. For example, you create 5 `introduction` objects. You only need 1, then call the methods from that single one. I'm guessing this is the main cause of your issues. You have a similar problem with creating many `random` objects.

Comment: HINT: You only need **1 introduction object** and **2 random objects** _(one for user input and one for random number)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random` is a class, and you can have any number of instances (objects) of that class.  Each instance contains its *own* versions of `number` and `guessNum`.  If you create two `new random()` objects, `object1` and `object2`, and you do something that assigns to `object1.number`, and then you look at the value of `object2.number`, it will *not* be the value that you assigned to `object1.number`.

That's the problem with your code.  You create one object `pickRandNumber`, and then call a method that sets `pickRandNumber.number`.  You create another object `readyMessage` and then call a method that asks for user input and then sets `readyMessage.guessNum`.  Then you create two new objects, and try to get the `number` and `guessNum` from the new objects.  Those new objects have their *own* `number` and `guessNum` values, which you haven't set to anything--you've set the values of `number` and `guessNum` in different objects.

The solution is to rewrite `main()` to use the right objects.  So after

```
random pickRandNumber = new random();
pickRandNumber.pickRandom();
```

that will set `pickRandNumber.number`, and if you want to retrieve that number, use something like:

```
if (pickRandNumber.getNumber() == ....)
```